# call get method from a html herf in mvc core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Html herf

```
 href="/DeviceMst/Index/"
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<DEVICE_MASTER> devices = db.DEVICE_MASTER;
        return View(devices);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Get_status(GetId getId)
    {
        //logic

        return Json("Success");
    }
```

the problem is
Whenever I call get method by clicking "a" tag, it also called the post method even after changing the name of the post method.

I am new to mvc core.

Comment: Can you please post the whole html code.

Comment: thanks, i found the issue. there is one post method in script.

Comment: I just wanted to write. There is no reason to hit the post method for href. Also, you can remove the  [HttpGet] attribute from the Index() method and by default, it is a get type.

Comment: `<a>`  tag can't call post method in backend,  Have you added [HttpPost] attribute correctly?